ECS celery task stopping after running for a few minutes
I have an api working fine on ecs, aws. I am however trying to run celery on a different service along side the api but it shuts down after a few minutes. It terminates with django.db.utils.OperationalError: connection failed: server closed the connection unexpectedly error. I dont undersatnd why it is behaving like this yet the db is working fine and the connections havent reached maximum. What might be the issue?
